# Are "If only there was a way" comments 'not constructive'?

Tags: discussion, comments, not-constructive

I recently came across a question that was an admittedly poor question about having multiple classes and interfaces in the same Java source file. The very first comment read:

```
If only there was a way to test this yourself.
```

I flagged this as not constructive, because it's not teaching anyone anything. Sure, their bit of sarcasm is true, that there is a way to test this themselves, but I could make the assumption that OP didn't think of just trying it themselves, or if they did were looking for an answer as to why. Surely there are more constructive ways to say that, such as:

```
Have you tried testing it yourself to see what would happen?
```

After going back, I see now the comment is still there and has 5 upvotes. Certainly even those who ask bad questions deserve a chance to be helped, rather than bombarded with sarcasm and downvotes.

I just can't understand what *is* constructive about that comment. Can anyone clear that up for me?

Comment: If only there was a way for you to leave a more constructive comment yourself.

Comment: +1 for sarcasm and only because this is meta. I have left a comment, but I still am curious as to why that flag was declined.

Comment: Remember people: downvoting indicates disagreement on [meta-tag:feature-request]s, not on [meta-tag:discussion]s.

Comment: You're right. It's not constructive but snarky. The point can be made in a more constructive manner, and we should try to avoid comments like this.

Comment: Flag such comments as too chatty. Also, focus on the post rather than comments and try to add a better comment yourself.

Comment: What I find more offensive is the close vote for "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource."  Horseshit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I flagged this as not constructive, because it's not teaching anyone
>   anything.

While the comment is rather snarky, it is teaching the question asker (or at least that's how I read the commenter's intent; see [Jeroen Vannevel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276905/3920237) for context) that they should try to compile the code themselves before asking a question. It's not unusual to see "have you tried running the code yourself?" type of comments in questions that consist of a code dump and asks "will this code work?"

If we take a look at [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) we see a brief explanation of what the various flagging reasons mean:

> - rude or offensive — comments that violate the [“be nice”
>     rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)
> - not constructive / off-topic — comments are meant to help improve
>     the post they're on, and comments that do not contribute for that are
>     rife for deletion
> - obsolete — for example, criticism of a post that has been
>     satisfactorily addressed by the author
> - chatty — anything that's not really relevant (e.g. [“+1”
>     comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/are-all-the-1-comments-really-necessary/15292#15292))

And the ["be nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice):

> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom
>      you want to respect you. *If you don't have time to say something
>      politely, just leave it for someone who does.*

So I would say that you should've flagged it as rude or offensive instead and left a more constructive comment.

Answer (score 7):

I have no problem admitting this was [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938532/multiple-public-class-and-interface#comment42421316_26938532) so I will reiterate my response:

> "Testing" here is exactly the same as "Copy precisely what you just put here and execute it in your IDE". The help center clearly specifies *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.*, being able to execute your code isn't remotely near the level of competence that we expect.

For context: the question was this:

> Can i declare `public interface` and `public class` in same source file?? (without Nesting)

As to whether it is constructive: sure, in a way. Maybe not in another way. Regardless: I don't feel like I crossed the boundaries so I will not adjust the way I address users that don't make any effort to solve or research their question.